# CSS and images get 404 error but path is correct

Tags: css, image, path, http-status-code-404, subdomain

I am trying for the first time to organize a project with two subdomains and I have been stuck for several days:

**1 -** My project is organized as follows and works very well locally:

```
project/
    |—— admin/
    |      index.php
    |      .htacess
    |      …
    |—— shared/
    |      |—— config/
    |      |      config.php
    |      |      …
    |      css/
    |      images/
    |      functions/
    |      …
    |—— user/
    |     index.php
    |     .htacess
    |     …
```

**2 -** Project is hosted by on a shared server (not sure if this is useful information).

**3 -** I currently have 2 subdomains: "admin.website.fr" and "user.wbesite.fr", which respectively have my "admin" and "user" folders as their roots.

**4 -** My "config" and "shared" folders, as you can imagine, both contain files common to "admin" and "user".

**5 -** Here is the content of my ".htacess" file :

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg            "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml         "access plus 1 week"
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    ExpiresByType image/ico             "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/icon            "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon          "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/css              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript       "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/html             "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml     "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript  "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.user.website.fr/$1 [R,L]


Options -Indexes
```

---

When I access "user.website.fr", the css and images do not load on my "index.php" page (404 error). I have checked the path many times, and there are no special restrictions on the "shared" folder since I can access the contents of my "config/config.php" file in the "shared" folder in the same way using "DIR". I tried to print the path and it seems correct each time but still I have 404 error. Also tried with relative paths.

**My questions :**

**1 -** What could be causing this ? Could it be the ".htacess" file ?

**2 -** In this subdomain configuration, do I need an ".htaccess" file at the root of each subdomain?

I'm running out of ideas at this point...

Comment: From the 404 errors in the console you can see in which path it's looking for the resources. Do you see problems in the path?

Comment: No, from that I can see that the path is correct...

Comment: You haven't told us what URLs are being requested or shown us the part of the server configuration responsible for specifying the DocumentRoot.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `admin` and `user` folder are the document roots for each respective subdomain? So what paths are you actually using to try and refer to those images and stylesheets then? You can't go "above" or outside the document root with HTTP requests.

Comment: I did not know that unfortunately. I was indeed trying to refer to those css and images that are in the `shared` folder outside of the document root and not a subdomain folder.

Here is an example of links in my html head tag : 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo __DIR__. '/../shared/css/animateLogin.css'?>" type="text/css">` .

Now I know they can't be accessible for the browsers with http request outside of my www/web directory, but how can I manage to "reach" them and keep my project structure as it is now ? As they are common files for my `admin` an `user` subdomains/folders...